# Powershell interactive Menu, Menu options from text file

Tags: powershell, menu, interactive

I'm trying to create an interactive menu in Powershell. Now, I want to know if its possible to get the menu options to come out of a text file:

```
function GetMenu {    
Clear-Host
Write-Ascii -fore green "Berechtigungen"
""
"1)Root Folder"
"2)Sub Folder"
"3)Delete Folder"
"4)Add User"
""
"x) Exit"
""
$MenuSelection = Read-Host "Choose Option"
GetSubMenu
} 
GetMenu



###########################################
function GetSubMenu {
write-host ""
switch -wildcard ($MenuSelection) {
    "1" 
    {
    function GetSubMenuRoot {
write-host ""
switch -wildcard ($MenuSelectionRoot) {
    "1" 
    {
    
    }
    "2" 
    {
    
    }
    "3" 
    {
    
    }
    "x" 
    {
        Clear-Host; 
        exit}
    default{Clear-Host;GetMenuRoot}
    }

}




function GetMenuRoot {    
Clear-Host
Write-Ascii -fore green "RootFolder"
""
"1)(From TextFile)"
"2)(From TextFile)"
"3)(From TextFile)"
""
"x) Exit"
""
$MenuSelectionRoot = Read-Host "Wähle Option"
GetSubMenuRoot
} 
GetMenuRoot

    
    }
    "2"
    {
    
    }
    "3"
    {
    
    }
    "4"
    {
    
    }       
    "x" {
        Clear-Host; 
        exit}
    default{Clear-Host;GetMenu}
}
    
}
```

The Text file looks like this:

```
Org;Share;
Sales;\\srvSales\Sales$\
IT;\\srvIT\IT$\
CEO;\\srvCEO\CEO$\
```

(from textfile) should now be:

```
1)Salse
2)IT
3)CEO
```

As menu options

Sorry english isn't my first language if something is unclear please ask.

Comment: Your text file looks a lot like a CSV file, except that you use `;` instead of `,` as a delimiter. You might want to consider looking into [`Import-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.1), which will read in a CSV file and create an array of objects, each object having members corresponding to the names of the columns in the CSV file.

Comment: true, but how would i use the input from the csv for the menu options? 

   $dtImport = "D:\Files\PowerShell\Me\org.txt" 
   $arr1 = @()
   $r = Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path $dtImport
   $r.Org | foreach-object {$arr1 += $_}

something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a csv file, but considering that it's a text file (as you said), you can read the contents of your `.txt` file using `Get-Content` cmdlet.

```
$data = Get-Content '\YourTextFile.txt'
$orgValues = @()

foreach($line in $data[1 .. $data.Count]) #since you won't need the column name from first row
{
    $info = $line -split ';';
    $orgValues += $info[0]; #this contains your required values
}
```

You can then iterate through `$orgValues` to use them in your switch cases. Maybe something like this:

```
function GetMenuRoot 
{    
    Clear-Host
    $count = $orgValues.Count
    Write-Ascii -ForegroundColor green "RootFolder"
    ""
    for($i = 1; $i -le $orgValues.Length; $i++)
    {
        "$i) $($orgValues[$i - 1])"
        
    }
    $count++;
    "$count) Exit"
    ""
    
    $MenuSelectionRoot = Read-Host "Wähle Option"
    GetSubMenuRoot
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, it gives me the correct output but i cant manage to get it correct in my code so i can use the $orgValues in the menu.

Comment: @Naimad - You can iterate through the `$orgValues` and wrap your `Write-Ascii` and your `switch` loop inside it, should be simple to do.

Comment: @Naimad - added sample code to help you understand how to iterate through `$orgValues` in your use case. Hope this helps.

Comment: it was fine even though i starte a new attempt with a gui but thank you very much